# remediation for security related issues

Tags: audit

I have a report by foresiet for a company's website.
There's a bunch of files in the output.
One example in App Misconfiguration :

```
344
x.x.x.x
my-domain.io
Weak SSH cipher supported!
Medium
Open
Found in scan

345
x.x.x.x
my-domain.io
Weak SSH KEX algorithms supported!
Medium
Open
Found in scan.
```

Where can I find remediation for such ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a hardening guide created for your operating system.  For example, the Center for Internet Security (CIS) offers a wide range of hardening guides.

NOTE: These are examples, do your own research to get the latest configurations.

For the weak SSH cipher, add/replace this variable in your sshd_config file:

> Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128- gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr

For the weak KEX algorithms, add/replace this line in your sshd_config:

> KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2- nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange- sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

**References**
[Center for Internet Security](https://www.cisecurity.org/)